# Vertex normals incorrect after scaling

Tags: opengl-es, normals

I am displaying a scene and everything looks fine.
When I scale an object I notice that the lighting becomes different (darker as the object get larger). I know I can recalculate the normals but is there any way I can tell opengl to do this automatically? I am using opengles 2.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scaling of the object should be performed through the model matrix, and hence the original normal vectors of the object need not be changed. When transforming the model with a model matrix, you must also transform the normals accordingly. See http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_normaltransform.html .

Answer (score 0):

The normals do not change even if you apply scaling. This means you do not have to recalculate the normals every time. The issue is most likely in the normal matrix that you calculate. Make sure that the normal matrix(which is the inverse and transpose of you model view matrix) has the scaling parameters.

Cheers!!!